# Why is this easy comparison false?

Tags: r

Why does this simple statement evaluate to `FALSE` in R?

```
mean(c(7.18, 7.13)) == 7.155
```

Furthermore, what do I have to do in order to make this a `TRUE` statement? Thanks!

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: `isTRUE(all.equal(mean(c(7.18, 7.13)),7.155))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+faq+7.31

Comment: OK, @BenBolker's comments are somewhat more insightful than my "answer", but the idea is the same.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a little grumpy about this, but we shouldn't be answering this question again. Thanks to @T.C. for the link to the canonical duplicate ...

Comment: @BenBolker I didn't search for the question before I answered it (maybe I should have), but tbh I'd never read an answer before (although I'm not surprised it already exists).

Comment: @BenBolker, that's a pretty unlikely Stack Overflow search term you shared there :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558) has more information.

You can actually see this:

```
> print(mean(c(7.18,7.13)), digits=16)
[1] 7.154999999999999
> print(7.155, digits=16)
[1] 7.155
```

In general, do not compare floating point numbers for equality (this applies to pretty much every programming language, not just R).

You can use `all.equal` to do an inexact comparison:

```
> all.equal(mean(c(7.18,7.13)), 7.155)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably due to small rounding error. Rounding to the third decimal place shows that they are equal:

`round(mean(c(7.18, 7.13)), 3) == 7.155`

Generally, don't rely on numerical comparisons to give expected logical outputs :)